# Modify Laravel Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with a public repo (https://github.com/LearningLocker/learninglocker) to put this site on an https:// server. It works fine on http://, but The entire site doesn't load (scripts, css, POST forms), etc, because all the links are prepended with http.

I noticed that the scripts had echo HTML~ prepended to it.

```
<?php echo HTML::style('assets/css/app.css'); ?>
```

I traced it and found that it was an alias to a Laravel class.  How can I modify all instances of HTML to point to a custom site e.g. https://mysite.com? or have it return this from the class?

```
'aliases' => array(
    'HTML'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
    'Log'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Paginator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',

),
```

Thanks for any help you can give, i have no PHP experience, but i want to make this work.

Comment: Perhaps look into these helpers provided by Laravel? http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls You can use `asset()` or `secure_asset()` without having to overwrite Laravel core library.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to overcome this problem. `Laravel` provides functionality to generate `links/assets` with `https`, for example:

```
echo link_to_asset('...', $title, $attributes = array(), $secure = null);
secure_url('...', $parameters = array());
url('...', $parameters = array(), $secure = null);
```

You should check [Helpers -> URLS](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls).

Comment: Is editing the htaccess in some way an approach to fixing this ? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/forcing-ssl-and-www-in-htaccess

Comment: It's related and you got answers there.